# Setting event color's in Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

Using the [Google Calendar API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), I can successfully [add](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingSingle), [update](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#UpdatingEvents) and [delete](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#DeletingEvents) an event.

But I can't see a way to set the event color.  When the event is created, the default color is used.

Am I missing something?  It seems odd that other aspects (where, when, reminders) can be set via the api.  Is it possible to change it?

[image]

Comment: According to the answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-dataapi/browse_thread/thread/7cface46744101fe) event color is not exposed via api at this point.

Comment: I gather that Google only just implemented the feature a matter of days ago, so it will take some time to show up in the API.

Comment: I am seriously interested in writing a plugin or something based on a regex that changes all events matching to colour X. This is totally needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now do this using [v3 of the calendar API.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get)