# Event color settings are not preserved when a calendar is exported

Tags: google-calendar-api

Customized event colors (foreground and background) are not preserved when you export a calendar since there is no reference on the generated ics file about them. When the calendar is imported from the ics file, all the event color settings are lost. Is there any way to preserve the event color information using the Google Calendar API ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119147/setting-event-colors-in-google-calendar) and further drilling down to [this google calendar API post](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get),
Google API calendar currently does support that.